# Узнать внешний ip-адрес своего компьютера

Tags: c#, tcp-ip, ip-address

Как определить внешний Ip адрес своего компьютера на языке c#?

Comment: @FoggyFinder нашёл лишь устаревший метод

Comment: @FoggyFinder  
String host = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName();
System.Net.IPAddress ip = System.Net.Dns.GetHostByName(host).AddressList[0];

Comment: Уточните в вопросе, что вы имеете в виду под _IP-адрес своего компьютера_? Это локальный адрес (127.0.0.1), адрес во внутренней сети (192.168.*.* или 10.*.*.*), либо внешний (публичный) адрес? Какие вас интересуют?

Comment: `String host = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName()` Ну-ну... вот вернёт он тебе `vasya-pupkin.xxx.local` - и чё дальше?

Comment: @Akina вторая строчка же мой ip-адрес возвращает, только этот метод устаревший

Comment: Метод не устаревший. Метод - узкоспециализированный. Работает исключительно в том случае, когда компьютер имеет "белый" адрес и зарегистрирован на дефолтном DNS (статически или динамически).

Comment: @Akina Visual Studio считает его устаревшим)

Comment: Это означает лишь то, что VS намерено в одной из ближайших версий отказаться от поддержки этого метода. Либо полностью, либо превратив его в обёртку для нового метода с этим функционалом.

Answer (score 7):

Я пару раз пользовался вот таким образам:

```
string pubIp =  new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString("https://api.ipify.org");
```

тут много примеров https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3253701/get-public-external-ip-address

Answer (score 6):

Полагаю, что тривиальное решение с обращением к внешнему сервису не требуется?

Выполните трассировку на любой доступный публичный адрес. Первый не-приватный адрес в цепи - это почти наверняка адрес дефолтного шлюза внешнего маршрутизатора. Для определения его (самого маршрутизатора) адреса нужно оттрассировать все адреса подсети найденного дефолтного шлюза - при трассировке до внешнего адреса получите на 1 хоп меньше, чем до остальных адресов подсети.

PS1. Поскольку гарантированного способа определить маску подсети дефолтного шлюза имхо нет, придётся делать какие-то допущения. Впрочем, провайдеры редко выделяют под вывод клиентов широкий пул.

PS2. Провайдер запросто может учинить бяку и перекосячить трассировку (узлы могут не отвечать или нештатно менять TTL). А если у него OSPF с несколькими равноценными маршрутами, трасссировка может вообще превратиться в ходячий цирк.

PS3. Провайдер может иметь несколько внешних каналов, и твой внешний адрес будет зависеть от чего угодно - начиная с адреса узла назначения и кончая ценой на рис в Антарктиде...

PS4. И это ещё только для случая, когда выход в мир - прямой. А не приведи господи у тебя прокся какая-нибудь...