# Как узнать внешний IP-адрес клиента?

Tags: c#, .net

Можно ли узнать с каким IP пользователь выходит в глобальную сеть? Использование сервисов не вариант потому, что например если он использует VPN, то буду получать IP VPN-a, а не IP, который подключился к этому VPN.

Comment: Одна из задач, для которых используются прокси и VPN, это скрытие реального IP. Так что общий ответ - нет, нельзя, если прокси специально не отправляет исходный IP в заголовках. Ну а в случае VPN нельзя практически в 100% случаев.

Comment: Можно по подробней с какой стороны вы это пытаетесь узнать? а то если так с ходу, то никак)) На то собственно и делаются VPN, proxy, tor и прочие "мосты"))

Comment: Можно организовать трейс-роут, от туда будет видна вся цепочка, останется только отпарсить адреса. Это со стороны клиента естественно.

Comment: @AtachiShadow это делается со стороны клиента. Т.е. у клиента запускается .exe на .NET и вот в этом .exe хочу узнать его IP.

Comment: @J.Huxley Зачем вам такие данные? Если человек сидит за VPN и скрывает свой IP - значит на то есть причины. А без его ведома узнавать такие данные - за такие вещи как минимум по пальцам бьют.

Comment: @ГеннадийП а если написать в пользовательском соглашении какие мы данные собираем? Кто тогда будет бить по пальцам?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Узнать внешний ip-адрес своего компьютера](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/608583/%d0%a3%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-ip-%d0%b0%d0%b4%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81-%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bf%d1%8c%d1%8e%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0)